# Strategies for avoiding python scope errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, jupyter-notebook

I use IPython Notebooks extensively in my research. I find them to be a wonderful tool.

However, on more than one occasion, I have been bitten by subtle bugs stemming from variable scope. For example, I will be doing some exploratory analysis:

```
foo = 1
bar = 2
foo + bar
```

And I decide that `foo + bar` is a useful algorithm for my purposes, so I encapsulate it in a function to make it easier to apply to a wider range of inputs:

```
def the_function(foo, bar):
    return foo + bar
```

Inevitably, somewhere down the line, after building a workflow from the ground up, I will have a typo somewhere (e.g. `def the_function(fooo, bar):`) that causes a global variable to be used (and/or modified) in a function call. This causes unseen side effects and leads to spurious results. But because it typically returns a result, it can be difficult to find where the problem actually occurs.

Now, I recognize that this behavior is a feature, which I deliberately use often (for convenience, or for necessity i.e. function closures or decorators). But as I keep running into bugs, I'm thinking I need a better strategy for avoiding such problems (current strategy = "be careful").

For example, one strategy might be to always prepend '_' to local variable names. But I'm curious if there are not other strategies - even "pythonic" strategies, or community encouraged strategies.

I know that python 2.x differs in some regards to python 3.x in scoping - I use python 3.x.

Also, strategies should consider the interactive nature of scientific computing, as would be used in an IPython Notebook venue.

Thoughts?

**EDIT**: To be more specific, I am looking for IPython Notebook strategies.

Comment: Use modules and avoid globals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I made my own solution to the problem. It builds on both answers given so far.

You can find my solution, which is a cell magic extension, on github: https://github.com/brazilbean/modulemagic

In brief, this extension gives you the ability to create %%module cells in the notebook. These cells are saved as a file and imported back into your session. It effectively accomplishes what @shadanan had suggested, but allows you to keep all your work in the same place (convenient, and in line with the Notebook philosophy of providing code and results in the same place).

Because the import process sandboxes the code, it solves all of the scope shadowing errors that motivated my original question. It also involves little to no overhead to use - no renaming of variables, having other editors open, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I was tempted to flag this question as too broad, but perhaps the following will help you.

When you decide to wrap some useful code in a function, write some tests.  If you think the code is useful, you must have used it with some examples.  Write the test first lest you 'forget'.

My personal policy for a library module is to run the test in an `if __name__
== '__main__':` statement, whether the test code is in the same file or a different file.  I also execute the file to run the tests multiple times during a programming session, after every small unit of change (trivial in Idle or similar IDE).

Use a code checker program, which will catch some typo-based errors.  "'fooo' set but never used".

Keep track of the particular kinds of errors *you* make, analyze them and think about personal countermeasures, or at least learn to recognize the symptoms.

Looking at your example, when you do write a function, don't use the same names for both global objects and parameters.  In your example, delete or change the global 'foo' and 'bar' or use something else for parameter names.

Comment: I appreciate these suggestions. Because I am working in an IPython Notebook, the IDE tools you mention aren't available. I think you're right that unit testing is a good strategy for avoiding the errors I describe - I'll consider that.

Comment: Using different variable names is essentially the same as the example strategy in my question. Prepending '_' keeps the variable purpose clear while avoiding collisions with the global namespace; however, it's easy to forgot or overlook (leading to the original problem). Renaming all variables can avoid this, but the downside is that you have to come up with new names for the concepts you've developed so far - the most obvious names are already chosen (used in the global namespace), so now you have obfuscated/one-off names in the functions.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you separate your concerns. For your exploratory analysis, write your code in the iPython notebook, but when you've decided that there are some functions that are useful, instead, open up an editor and put your functions into a python file which you can then import.

You can use iPython magics to auto reload things you've imported. So once you've tested them in iPython, you can simply copy them to your module. This way, the scope of your functions is isolated from your notebook. An additional advantage is that when you're ready to run things in a headless environment, you already have your entire codebase in one place.